# How can I programmatically invoke a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run the map object's click event in the following code
function e takes coordinates of the mouse click on the map. I want to define a destination point so I need to invoke the click event

```
function setupRoutingAPI(map, ghRouting) {
     map.on('click', function (e) {});

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to `trigger("click")` on `map`

```
map.trigger("click");
```

After the even is established. If the event is not defined, it will not trigger.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can do

```
$( '.map' ).trigger('click');
```

or plain JavaScript example

```
var map = document.getElementById('map');
map.onclick();
```

**UPDATE**

So the plain JS example doesn't work though the

```
map.click();
```

is functional and triggers the event on the element

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m5f9g7ft/4/

Comment: listener for the click event does not work for the above javascript code

Comment: <div id="routing-map" class="map"></div> I will try to click on that element   in my html code exactly

Answer (score 0):

Abstract the function out of the click event to make it reusable.  Then pass that function into the click event by name and call it when you need it.

Comment: js is an event driven language, so I think it should be used as such. Triggering an actual click event would be much cleaner imo.

Comment: impersonating a click event is hacky.  It's unnecessary, less semantic, more code, and less reusable.  If you want to bind that same function to another event then you will have more issues.